# "Invalid controller specified" error in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, controller

i used zf tool to create a project in "http://localhost/work/qwafel"

i created it the url "http://localhost/work/qwafel/public" display index controller index action ok. but when i navigate to "http://localhost/work/qwafel/public/index" i got this error

```
An error occurred

Page not found

Exception information:

Message: Invalid controller specified (work)

Stack trace:

#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Work\qwafel\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Work\qwafel\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Work\qwafel\library\Zend\Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\Work\qwafel\public\index.php(26): Zend_Application->run()
#4 {main}  
Request Parameters:

array (
  'controller' => 'work',
  'action' => 'qwafel',
  'public' => 'index',
  'module' => 'default',
)
```

I don't know why i created many projects with zf tool it was working properly

nobody there? help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well when you create a zf-project using zf command line tool it always has a `IndexController` and an `indexAction` function. So you should be able to run it.

However there seems to be something wrong with your project setup. I can copy my zend project to any directory in my htdocs folder, it will still work.

Open command line tool and navigate to any directory and create a project:

```
zf create project test
```

Don't modify the project, copy it to any folder in htdocs. Everything is fine for me right now.

Comment: thanks for participating but it now work whatever where i create the project i think it was problem with the server ! maybe.

Answer (score 0):

To install Zend Framework in a sub-folder is a little more tricky.

Edit your .htaccess to have:

```
RewriteBase /work/qwafel
```

That should do it...

Comment: many other zend framework projects are in sub sub folders and work fine but this has problem why? i don't know

Comment: Check to see if your .htaccess has a RewriteBase set. Change it to match your folder structure. I added that to the answer

Comment: I add this line but no effect it gave me no error more than not found 404 error page when I removed this line again it worked! isn't this crazy?

Comment: Uhhh... that is weird. I guess removing the line altogether did the trick? I believe my Zent_Tool put in the rewrite base as / by default.

Comment: we develop project to work any where not in a specified directory its generic